# Incorrect pad error in Pycryptodome. Encrypted in CryptoJS

Tags: cryptography, padding, cryptojs, pycryptodome

I use the following to encrypt in Javascript

```js
function encrypt(input, key){
    console.log("Input: " + input);  
    var secret_key = CryptoJS.SHA256(key);
    var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);
    console.log("IV: "+ iv);
    var body = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(input, secret_key, {iv: iv,mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7});
    iv.concat(body.ciphertext);
    return toBase64String(iv);
}
```

This is how I decrypt in Python/Django/Pycryptodome:

```py
def actsignin(request):
    global key
    global prime
    global base_num

    encrypted_string = request.GET['encrypted_string']

    print("Encrypted string decoded: ",base64.b64decode(encrypted_string).hex())
    print("----")
    encrypted = base64.b64decode(encrypted_string)
    IV = encrypted[:BLOCK_SIZE]
    print("IV: ",IV)
    sha256_key = SHA256.new(data=bytes(key))
    cipher = AES.new(sha256_key.digest(),AES.MODE_CBC)
    print(unpad(cipher.decrypt(encrypted[BLOCK_SIZE:]),BLOCK_SIZE))
    print('in signin')
    return render(request,"Shenzen/display.html",{'student':'student'})
```

It still says that

```
Encrypted string decoded:  d9c9c21a9c2b5f46bc89933d82e1c1ef6c36dee1dc448b596d28bd3b5db45323
----
IV:  b'\xd9\xc9\xc2\x1a\x9c+_F\xbc\x89\x93=\x82\xe1\xc1\xef'
Internal Server Error: /Shenzen/actsignin/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tarunmaganti/Documents/AbhiramSlavery/ProjectLogin/hell/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/tarunmaganti/Documents/AbhiramSlavery/ProjectLogin/hell/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/tarunmaganti/Documents/AbhiramSlavery/ProjectLogin/hell/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/tarunmaganti/Documents/AbhiramSlavery/ProjectLogin/UrbanHell/Shenzen/views.py", line 82, in actsignin
    print(unpad(cipher.decrypt(encrypted[BLOCK_SIZE:]),BLOCK_SIZE))
  File "/home/tarunmaganti/Documents/AbhiramSlavery/ProjectLogin/hell/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Crypto/Util/Padding.py", line 90, in unpad
    raise ValueError("Padding is incorrect.")
```

BLOCK_SIZE is 16 and Key is generated using the DH algorithm.

---

### Issue:

Padding seems to be incorrect.
I seem to have used SHA256 for key on both sides.
IV output seems correct on both sides.
So, I'm operating on same string in both scenarios. Since, the padding generally takes place to the input string, I've decrypted and tried to unpad it in Python which says that the padding is incorrect.

---

Trying out the following comments:
1. IV was not passed in the python code.
The result did not change

2. Are you sure the key is the same.
   Using `console.log(secret_key.toString())` and `print("Sha256 of the key: ",sha256_key.digest())` in JS and Python respectively. Both were different. Why is that the case? Shouldn't the hash be the same for same input?

Comment: Decrypt in `No Padding` mode.  That should either give complete rubbish -- you have a decryption error somewhere, not in the padding -- or you have a correct decryption with the padding added at the end.  Make sure your decryption code is expecting that type of encryption.

Comment: Are you sure the keys are same? Put a string over there?

Comment: In the Python-code the IV is not used, try: `cipher = AES.new(sha256_key.digest(), AES.MODE_CBC, IV)`

Comment: @Topaco I tried with IV and the result is the same.

Comment: @rossum Keys don't seem to be the same. But, why is that the case? I'm using SHA256 in both the cases. Shouldn't the hash be same for some value no matter what?

Comment: @kelalaka YES! You're right. The input in JS was a string. Whereas in Python it was an Integer. It works now.